# How to use ggplot to do the binned quantile plots(one type of scatter plot)?

Tags: data-visualization, ggplot2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do a pretty scatter plot in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24416/how-to-do-a-pretty-scatter-plot-in-r)

How to use ggplot to do the binned quantile plots(one type of scatter plot)?
Hi all,
I have done scatter plot: plot(x, y).
Now I wanted to do binned quantile plots... can ggplot2 help me?
For example, we bin x data into 10 bins.
For each bin, we draw the 10 deciles of the corresponding y data in that bin as points/dots.
And then accross all bins, we would like to connect the corresponding decile points/dots together(something like equi-quantile or equi-decile curves)...
How do I do that in R or ggplot2? Is there an existing function/command that can do this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know of a single function in ggplot that does this, so you'll have to build it up yourself. I'd suggest you make some attempts, and then come back and edit your question with more details when you get stuck.

Comment: This is a good question.  It asks for a version of Tukey's "wandering schematic plot," which was one of his more creative efforts to summarize scatterplot data.